# How to update Firestore with Dragula Events

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula

It seems impossible to make dragula drop events update the indexes in firestore, so the positions the user chooses can be saved. Even though the items change positions in the array

```
this.$note = this.afs.collection(`notes`, ref => ref.orderBy('priority'));
this.$notes = this.$note.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
       return actions.map(a => {
         const data = a.payload.doc.data();
         const id = a.payload.doc.id;
         return { id, data };
       });
     });

this.$notes.subscribe((noteArray) => {
  console.log('run when change');
  this.noteArray = [];
  for (const n of noteArray) {
    // console.log('run');
    this.noteArray.push(n);
  }

  this.dragulaService.drop.subscribe(() => {
    this.noteArray.forEach((note, index) => {
      // console.log("note", note, index);
      this.afs.doc(`notes/${note.id}`).update({ priority: index });
    });
    console.log("noteArray", this.noteArray);

    this.$notes.subscribe((nArray) => {
      console.log('run when change');
      this.noteArray = [];
      for (const n of nArray) {
        // console.log('run');
        this.noteArray.push(n);
      }
      console.log("nArry", this.noteArray);
  });
```